# Found the parameter of the elliptic integral of the first kind

Tags: elliptic-equations, elliptic-functions

Suppose I have:
$$\frac{p}{[K(p)-K(\frac{-\pi}{2},p)]^2} = x$$

[$K(p)$](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ellipk.html#scipy.special.ellipk) being the complete elliptic function of the first kind and [$K(\theta,p)$](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ellipkinc.html#scipy.special.ellipkinc) the incomplete elliptic function of the first kind.

How could I determine $p$ as a function of $x$?

I'm using scipy, I'm more of a programmer that a classical mathematician.

I've been looking into the [Jacobian elliptic functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ellipj.html#scipy.special.ellipj) but as I understand it, it's used to determine the angle of the elliptic function knowing the parameter.

**EDIT 1**
As [Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici) noticed, $K(-\frac{\pi}{2},p) = -K(p)$
So now I'm looking for $p$, knowing $y$ in:$$y = \frac{p}{K(p)^2}$$

Comment: Are you using Mathematica notation for $K(.)$ ?

Comment: Are you looking for the small root or both ?

Comment: I think the Mathematica notation for $K(.)$ is the same as [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ellipk.html#scipy.special.ellipk).  
Lets say $0≤p≤0.7$, I think there is only one solution in this interval.

Comment: There are two roots for any $0<p<1$  and no solution if $y>0.162522$. Which root do you want ?

Comment: I'm sorry Claude, as I said I'm no mathematician. I'm looking for the smallest $p$, does that mean I'm looking for the smallest root?

Comment: As written, your post does not meet the standards of the site. If you do not that the question closed : explain what you alreasy tried, the problems you faced, where you are stuck. Also precise if you want an algorithm or a good approximation of the solution (what kind of accuracy ?). So, edit the post and once things will be clarified, I shall post

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, you can firstly plot $y$ in function of $p$:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import ellipk

p = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
K = ellipk(p)
y = p / K**2
plt.plot(p, y)
```

[image]

Say you want the values $p$ giving $y=0.12$. This graphic allows you to get an idea of the values of $p$, say $0.4$ and $0.9$. Then you can use `fsolve`

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
ytarget = 0.12
f = lambda x: x / ellipk(x)**2 - ytarget
fsolve(f, [0.4, 0.9])
# output: array([0.37077373, 0.93649696])
```